# maven build offline error- must specify a valid lifecycle phase

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am still getting the hang of Maven and spring, but am having an odd problem.

Up until a few days ago I could build maven fine by using the command:

```
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean install eclipse:eclipse –o
```

not sure what changed but i started getting the error:

```
BUILD FAILURE
Invalid task 'uo': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, 
or a goal in the format plugin:goal or 
pluginGroupIf:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal
for mor information run with the -e switch
```

I tried updating all my code from SVN and got the same error. I finally completed building all packages with online with:
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean install eclipse:eclipse

which gave be BUILD SUCCESSFUL for all project packages.

Yet when I try building maven offline again i continue to get the same Build Failure error. Any thoughts?

Note: there is about 8 packages in my project and they all get the same build failure error

Comment: Try to run with the `-e` option and put the stacktrace here. Also put your POM file so we can see what could be wrong

Comment: Why are you calling `eclipse:eclipse`?

Comment: I am not allowed to post code specifics online unfortunately but i can say since each of the projects has a different POM and they all work for everyone else on my team and none work for me that is likely not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`–` character is incorrect use `-` instead, in your command

change this

```
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean install eclipse:eclipse –o
```

to

```
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean install eclipse:eclipse -o
```

Note: there is change in `-` hyphen character

Comment: thats crazy, this worked! I dont understand how though. The command that i use i copy from a team document everytime i use it, and i dont know how to even make that long dash. But i tried retyping the dash and it works! thanks

Comment: yes i figured it was copy and paste typo most probably copied from PDF